# Train AWS Sagemaker Object detection algorythm with empty images?

Tags: object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I want to train Sagemaker Object detection algorythm with my own dataset and want to know if the dataset must have images without object or not.

My dataset comes from Ground Truth with images from an outdoor camera, somes with object labelled, some without label (no object).

Answer (score 0):

yes, absolutely. This will help you model learn better. For example, the Caltech-256 dataset has a clutter class (#257) with random images containing no objects: http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech256/images/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will add them.